# Opendaylight Nitrogen: Unable to Install features

Tags: karaf, opendaylight

I am getting an error while installing the features.

```
 error executing command: error restarting bundles
```

Initially, it worked fine for some of the features but then it suddenly started throwing this error.

Any suggestion on this would be appreciated.

Comment: which version of opendaylight are you using? also, are you installing features on the karaf console with feature:install, or using featuresBoot config?

Comment: I am using Nitrogen, karaf 0.7.2. The installations is Ubuntu based VM where I have installed ODL. Yes, I am using the command "feature:install <feature_name>"

Comment: What is the value of <featue_name> ?

Comment: Doesn't matter what I use. I tried "odl-dlux-core", "odl-l2switch-switch", "odl-restconf"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you clean karaf, you can resolve the issue, by running the following command, you can clean the karaf.

```
./karaf clean
```

Comment: Thanks Sridhar...I will try that out and let you know

Answer (score 1):

When OpenDaylight moved to karaf 4 there were problems identified with
installing features in the karaf shell one after the other. I think
you are hitting that problem.

you can try listing out all the features you want in the featuresBoot
variable of the etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg file.

You may also have some success trying to install on the karaf shell with
the following flag --no-auto-refresh, like this:

```
feature:install --no-auto-refresh odl-l2switch-switch
```

Also, as sridhar reddy noted, if you use "karaf clean" to start karaf it will
wipe the data/ folder (and more) so that old loaded features will not come
back in on startup and you will start "clean".

Comment: Thanks jamo....I tried running the command no-auto-refresh but unfortunately the error was still there. So, I ended up clearing the karaf data and now it works. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Is it possible to use no-auto-refresh while using featureBoot. Also is it possible to do verbose during featureBoot so that we can now which bundle is auto refreshing.